# What does an '@' character mean in a csh script

Tags: csh

I'm translating a csh script to bash an came across a line that looks like

```
@ lines = `grep num_lines ../config.txt | awk '{printf("%d",int($2))}' `
```

What does the '@' do here? 
I found some [documentation](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Csh.html#uh-33) stating that csh uses '@' for expressions. However, this looks like a normal variable assignment to me. When I run the grep and awk part of the code in bash the output is an integer with a preceding '%d', e.g. '%d 12045'.

Comment: Are you sure that the `awk` command says `print` and not `printf`?

Comment: That line's broken and never worked properly. It will die out with an `Ambiguous` error. (or `Expression Syntax` in `tcsh`).

Comment: @Scott You are right, it's printf indeed.

Comment: No need for `grep`. Use `lines=$(awk '/num_lines/ {print $2}' ../config.txt)` or even `lines=$(awk '$1=="num_lines" {print $2}' ../config.txt)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it’s impossible to know what the author of that script was thinking. 
But here are some observations:

- If the `awk` command, indeed, says `printf`,
  then it is printing the integer value of the second string on the input line.
- As [roaima commented](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/518342/80216#comment958252_518342), and as I have been known to comment,
  `awk` is a very powerful program. 
  You almost never need to run it in combination
  with `grep`, `sed`, or another `awk`. 
  So

  ```
  grep num_lines filename | awk '{ printf("%d", int($2)) }'
  ```

  can be written

  ```
  awk '/num_lines/ { printf("%d", int($2)) }' filename
  ```
- As I mentioned above, `int($2)` gives you *the integer part*
  of the second string on the input line. 
  So, if the config file says `num_lines   foo`, you will get `0`. 
  If it says `num_lines   3.14`, you will get `3`. 
  It seems unlikely that you would need to take such precautions
  with a well-formed configuration file.
- In any case,

  ```
  printf("%d", int($2))
  ```

  is overkill. 
  As far as I can tell,

  ```
  printf("%d", $2)
  ```

  and

  ```
  print int($2)
  ```

  are (almost) exactly equivalent.
- The one difference that I can identify
  is that the `printf` version doesn’t write a newline at the end:

  ```
  $ echo "num_lines   42" | awk '{printf("%d", $2)}'; date
  42Mon, May 13, 2019 12:00:00 AM
   
  $ echo "num_lines   42" | awk '{print int($2)}'; date
  42
  Mon, May 13, 2019 12:00:01 AM
  ```

  but this isn’t really relevant,
  since `` `…` `` strips off a trailing newline.
- You say “this looks like a normal variable assignment to me”. 
  But users of [t]csh know that it doesn’t allow

  ```
  variable=value
  ```

  you have to say

  ```
  set variable=value
  ```

  or

  ```
  @ variable=expr
  ```

  Of course a simple integer constant is a valid *`expr`,*
  so the author may simply be using `@` instead of `set`
  because it’s shorter and they know that the value is an integer.

So the statement is setting the `lines` variable
to the value of `num_lines` from `../config.txt`.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer! I did not know this convenient way to look for specific strings with awk. `lines=$( awk '/num_lines/ {print int($2)}'  ../config.txt )` works perfect (in bash).